# MDI - How to persist focus on child control?

Tags: c#, forms, mdi

In the constructor of the child I call `control.Focus()` on a specific control. The hope is that it can maintain focus once a child form is created within the MDI parent. From what I gather the MDI parent is taking focus once the child is created.

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything on line that I found but figured out a quick and easy way. I'm posting just in case anyone else runs into this in the future.

Just setting `control.focus();`wasn't enough. Because when the child form was created, the MDI took focus.

I then realized it will only take focus one time, so I added the `control.focus()` statement in a `private void control_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)` as well as in the constructor.. so on focus leave, it will call focus to the control again. Fixed this issue for me without having to parse the list of child controls (which was a nightmare).